# Insertion time out error in Couchbase from springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

```sh
Unable To save identifier IN COUCHBASE, identifier: identifiertail::123::459, , Details: com.couchbase.client.core.error.AmbiguousTimeoutException: 
 UpsertRequest, Reason: TIMEOUT 
 "scope":"_default","type":"kv"},"timeoutMs":30000,"timings":{"encodingMicros":102,"totalMicros":36987410}}
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.cancel(BaseRequest.java:163)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.Timer.lambda$register$2(Timer.java:157)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:672)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:747)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:472)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Got above error while inserting records from app in logs. But when I checked the file, it was inserted and errors stopped coming after restart of `Pods`.

What could be reason that got fixed with the `Pod` restart?

Few things to add to this:

- Couchbase cluster was healthy.
- Network connectivity was good.
- spring boot version: 4.1
- Couchbase: 6.0.3
- connect timeout: 60s

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: you've mentioned pods, is this a kubernetes deployment?

Comment: yes it is Kubernetes deployment

Comment: faced similar kind of issue. issue was assigned memory to bucket was full. increased bucket memory and it worked.